# Colouring maximizing the weight of coloured edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring

I would like to know if the following problem has been studied in the literature:

We are given a edge-weighted undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ together with a set of available colours $C_v$ for each node $v \in V$. Find a colouring of $V$ (i.e., a function that picks a colour from $C_v$ for each vertex $v$) such that the weight of the unicolour edges is maximized. We call an edge unicolour if its vertices have the same colour.

Thanks!

Comment: When $k=2$, it is known as the Maximum cut problem, which is NP-C. Here's the wiki link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut

Comment: Clearly not. Maxcut is about cutting edges such that the volume of cut edges is maximized. Here, he wants to maximize the volume of uncut edges. Hence, minimize the volume of cut edges. It's mincut.

Comment: @davcha mincut is basically maxcut with negative weights.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like clustering.

Basically, you have an edge-weighted undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and you seek a k-partitioning of the nodes, such that the number or volume (depending on the objective function) of inter-cluster edges is minimized.

It is also known as graph cut problems.

You can read this : [Luxburg 2007](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5b0%5d.pdf), it's a good start on clustering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see that the problems are related, but what I think clustering is missing is that you cannot incorporate the colour restrictions, i.e., that some clusterings are feasible.

Comment: What are you calling "colour restriction" ?

Comment: The fact that different vertices can have different sets of available colours. For example, if their sets do not intersect, they cannot be in the same set of the clustering etc.

Comment: Oh right. Then, you have constrained clustering. Basically, you have a set of pairs of vertex that cannot-link in addition to edge weights. There is a lot of litterature about this. This is NP-complete problem for more than $2$ colors/clusters and usually the objective function you obtain is non convex.

Comment: Do you mean [Davidson, Ravi 2005]? True, I think you can also reduce k-colouring to our setting. Thanks! Last question: do you know if this has been also studied in the case of non-negative weights only?